# CLLocation geocodeAddressString result accuracy

Tags: mapkit, latitude-longitude, cllocation, geocode

I'm currently working on an app where the user inputs and address, which is then converted into coords. A database of locations is then queried and locations with in, say, 5km of search location is returned.

The problem I'm having is the accuracy returned by the geocodeAddressString function. When searching: Auckland, New Zealand, I'm getting back **-36.90000, 174.70000**, which is about 10 km's off the correct result. It's a few suburbs over.

Is there any way to improve on this? The Google Maps result is -36.848479, 174.763373, which you can see is much sharper and what I'm after.

Thanks!

Comment: There are three possibilities: you have multiple place marks in return, and you select the first one which is not precise enough. It's a float approximation issue. You need to provide a more precise address than Auckland, say the town hall for example. A piece of code would help us help  you.

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem as well. Not just in terms of reverse geocoding locations, but accuracy in geocoding an address string. For instance, if I enter "Primm, NV" on maps.google.com, no problems. If I use -geocodeAddressString:completionHandler: I end up with one and only one placemark: "Jean Nevada" instead. That's nearby Primm ... by about 20 km. Eek. As for my own sample code, it's as simple as making that one method call, then checking the results. Not much else going on.